# How does ros create communication between android device and linux pc?

Tags: usb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wanted to know how ros can communicate between an android and pc through an usb device. Looking at the hokuyo code in the android_extras, it implements the USB api, but this USB api is not picking up my linux machine as an usb device. So I wanted to know why the hokuyo code can create an connection between an android device and linux pc only using the usb.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201562/how-does-ros-create-communication-between-android-device-and-linux-pc?/) by [hat13](https://answers.ros.org/users/21397/hat13/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Hokuyo being used for that has a USB interface.

If you want to talk from a tablet to a PC with ROS you should use a USB ethernet adapter on the android device.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0